# Mysql workbench - Criar ou Alterar um evento

Tags: mysql

Nesse programa temos as opções de criar dentro de um schema:

- Tables
- Views
- Store Procedures
- Functions

Tudo de maneira interativa, mas não achei a opção de criar ***EVENTS***,

1. Será que existe em algum lugar essa opção, talvez um plugin para gerenciar os eventos?
2. Tem algum comando que me retorne o sql de construção ou alteração de um *Event* já criado? ( assim eu somente faria as alterações necessárias, não precisando digitar tudo )

Comment: Syntax para criar evento: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html

Comment: obrigado Kadu, mas eu queria mesmo é puxar as events que já escrevi no banco para fazer ajustes, mas pelo jeito terei que fazer na mão mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Talvez um pouco tarde a resposta, mas aqui vai:
passando o mouse sobre o schema, você verá um ícone `i` logo ao lado direito. Clique nele.

A ultima aba da tela que surgirá será a de Eventos. Configure ali seus eventos.
Abraco!

Comment: Oi Vinicius, vou testar, não é tarde demais não, foi a primeira resposta que recebi...rsrsrsr

Comment: Estou usando agora a versão 6.3.8 build 1228, e só da p/ visualizar os eventos que já tem, não tem como editar :(